# REPL not updating the code remotely - Clojure

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I am experiencing an API issue where a partner is trying to do a **POST** request to my server but it looks like it is loading the **previous code** from my server.

The **previous code** contained an error:

```
#'clj-time.coerce/ICoerce found for class: java.time.LocalDateTime
```

But it has been **fixed and released** through REPL.

Here is the **previous code**:

```
 (defn- parse-data [{:keys [name start-date bestbefore-date]}]
   {:product      name
    :start-date   (timec/to-string start-date)
    :bestbefore-date  (timec/to-string bestbefore-date)})
```

Here is the **fix** from the previous code:

```
(defn- parse-data [{:keys [name start-date bestbefore-date]}]
   {:product      name
    :start-date   (.toString (.format start-date formatter))
    :bestbefore-date  (.toString (.format bestbefore-date formatter))})
```

The code was working perfectly but it stopped after a few months as it **seems** to be loading the **previous code** containing the error mentioned above.

On my end, I tried to run the affected method from the request through REPL, and it is working just fine.

The server is built in **Clojure language**.

I have no other error logs aside from the partner error response as it is working fine on my server.

The server has not been restarted, so the fix should have been still there. Thus, I have again do an REPL with the code fix but it looks like it is not taking any effect.

As I am pretty new to Clojure, and I am thinking that it might be a cache issue. REPL concept is still pretty vague to me and perhaps I am doing something wrong.

I would like to know if some of you already experienced this kind of issue? And what would be the solution to it? Or perhaps any advice?

I wish to thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: You can _not_ permanently fix a remote system via the REPL. Once the remote end restarts, the Monkey Patch is gone. You have to put your fix into the (most likely) uberjar, that get's started.

Comment: Thanks for your response cfrick. So far I understand is that with the new uberjar file containing the new fix, then replacing the old uberjar will fix this? I am still pretty confused why it is working for me as I am running the code through REPL. When I update the jar file I always replace it with an updated one, thus keeping only one jar file.

Comment: Sorry, but I find this extremly confusing. Are you saying, that if you build/deploy a jar the supposedly fix does not track -- but if you are monkey patching via REPL it works? I'd recommend adding a MVE.

Comment: Perhaps my apologies for my English if I am not really clear. I would suggest, lets not think about the jar file for now, and lets consider only REPL. What I am saying is that I kept pushing the changes containing the fix through REPL(Monkey patching) which makes the function above working on my end, but how is this possible that the request fails by using the same API for my other third party(Partner)?

Comment: As an example, the API url is as follows: /api/request/create. The third party(partner) and I are both using the same end point for the request but it is only failing for the partner and not me. How is this possible?

Comment: Also, can I please know what is MVE?

Comment: See [Minimal
Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example);
There is no explanation, why one consumer would get a different problem
than you if they do the exact same.  So the most likely problem is: they
are not doing the same. It could be _anything_ from a load balancer,
hitting different endpoints to a standing connection, that never saw
your REPL patch. Without providing ways to reproduce the problem there
is slim hope, someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Kind a weird issue but I have been able to resolve this.

I was unsure what was going, so I just re-built the code and restarted the server.